# How to fix error: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (450,600,3) (277,330,3)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv

```
import math
import cv2
import numpy as np

original = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\HP\Documents\fyp\img\4.bmp", 1)
contrast = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\HP\Documents\fyp\img\dehaze4.png", 1)

def psnr(img1, img2):
    mse = np.mean((img1 - img2) ** 2)
    if mse == 0:
        return 100
    PIXEL_MAX = 255.0
    return 20 * math.log10(PIXEL_MAX / math.sqrt(mse))

d = psnr(original, contrast)
print(d)
```

**error**

```
runfile('C:/Users/HP/Documents/fyp/dcp/pnsr2.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/Documents/fyp/dcp')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\Documents\fyp\dcp\pnsr2.py:15 in <module>
    d = psnr(original, contrast)

  File ~\Documents\fyp\dcp\pnsr2.py:9 in psnr
    mse = np.mean((img1 - img2) ** 2)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (450,600,3) (277,330,3)
```

help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236. Regarding the question: what do you expect the width and height of each image to be? Did you check that? If you try to subtract two images from each other, and they don't have a matching width and a matching height, what do you think should happen? Why?

Comment: You are loading images with different sizes.  You can't take their difference without first resizing one or the other (to a common size).  Read the `cv2` docs for information on how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

The two images are of different shapes. I'm not sure what you're trying to do comparing two images of different sizes, but one way to do it is to resize one of the images to the size of the other:

```
def psnr(img1, img2):
    if img1.shape != img2.shape:
        img2 = cv2.resize(img2, img1.shape, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
```